# パーシャルのパーシャルに変数を送る方法を教えてください。

Tags: ruby-on-rails

#### 前提・実現したいこと

パーシャルのパーシャルにコントローラーのインスタンス変数を送りたいです。

#### ★発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

投稿のタイムラインをクリックすると、
Twitterのようなモーダルウィンドウが表示されるようにviewを作成しました。

モーダルウィンドウに表示される**view**(コメントが追加されます) ≒ クリックした投稿です。

一つのviewファイルで対応しますとかなりコードが読みづらくなりますので、パーシャルを置きました。

しかし、そのパーシャルを置いたviewファイルもパーシャルなので、変数がわたされなくなります。

結果、モーダルウィンドウには、内容などmicropostに関する情データが一切表示されなくなってしまいます。。。

【**microposts/_micropost.html.erb**】
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
【**microposts/_modal.html.erb**】
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

【パーシャルの流れ】
**index.html.erb → _user_index.html.erb  → _micropost.html.erb → _modal.html.html.erb**

※**_micropost.html.erb**までは正常にデータが送られている。。。
と思います。

#### ★該当のソースコード

【**page#index**】

```
@user = User.find_by(id: current_user.id)
@microposts = current_user.feed.includes(:comments, :calls, :insists, :says)
@micropost = current_user.microposts.build
```

【**_user_index.html.erb**】

```
<span class="index-microposts"><%= render partial: 'microposts/micropost', collection: @microposts, micropost: @micropost %></span>
```

【**_micropost.html.erb**】

```
<%= render 'microposts/modal', microposts: @microposts, micropost: @micropost %>
```

【**_modal.html.erb**】

```
<%= simple_format("#{markdown(micropost.content)}") %>
```

よろしければ、変数の送り方を教えてください。
そもそも、パーシャル多すぎなどのご指摘あればお願い致します。

マルチポスト
[テラテイル](https://teratail.com/questions/56907)

Answer (score 0):

以下のように `@micropost` から `micropost` に変更するとどうでしょうか？

`<%= render 'microposts/modal', microposts: @microposts, micropost: micropost %>`